# SwiftUI Background countdown timer

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have made a 'pomodoro' timer for myself to practice, which is effectively a timer that counts down from 25 minutes, then starts a 5 minute break, then counts down from 25 minutes again. This is done using a swift timer.

The problem I have is, if the app is closed or enters the background, then the timer stops counting. I have tried using a WillEnterBackground function to capture the date at the time of entering the background, and another date for when it enters the foreground, and subtracting them to find the elapsed time, but I can't figure out how to deal with the fact that this timer isn't just repeating an interval of 25 minutes, or even just counting down once - it's switching from 25 mins / 5 mins. Does anyone have a rough idea of how to deal with this ?

Comment: How about counting down from 30 minutes and then just using some logic to see if you're in the last five minutes or not to determine if you're in the break?

Comment: @jnpdx that's not a bad idea - thanks!

Comment: you could calculate the "alarm" times as specific points in time (Date), which you can save in UserDefaults, and use a regular repeating timer just to update the UI.